# Замена определённых вхождений php

Tags: php

Не могу найти подходящую функцию для замены определённых вхождений.

К примеру есть строка:
"Наша Таня громко плачет, уронила в речку мячик."

Задача стоит следующая, при каждом выполнении программы, скрипт должен находить все буквы "а" и заменять их на английскую "a". Причем не во всех сразу, а каждый раз в разных словах.

Я вижу выполнение задачи следующим образом:

При каждом выполнении программы, скрипт должен определять количество вхождений буквы "а", с помощью функции rand() получать случайное число в приделе количества найденных вхождений. И с помощью функции которую я ищу если она существует, заменять русские буквы на английские в приделе вхождений определённых через функцию rand().

Вот например в тексте для примера:

Представим что при первом выполнении скрипта в нашей строке найдено 5 вхождений.
Функция rand(0, 5) - получает число 3. Значит мы изменяем только первые 3 буквы "а". И тогда текст получается уже такой:

"Н**a**ш**a** Т**a**ня громко плачет, уронила в речку мячик."

При следующем выполнении rand(0, 5) - получает число 5. И тогда текст получается уже такой:

"Н**a**ш**a** Т**a**ня громко пл**a**чет, уронил**a** в речку мячик."

Ну и конце в концов нужно что бы не только букву "а" изменял но и "с,е,о и возможно и".

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли такая функция или как реализовать подобный скрипт.

Comment: Функции такой, разумеется, нет. "Как реализовать": очень просто - взять и написать самому.

Comment: "каждый раз в разных словах" - что имеется в виду? При каждом запуске скрипта будет какой-то свой список слов, в которых буква должна быть заменена? Или чисто случайно, в каких-то случайных словах?

Comment: @freim такой функции нет, принял. Взять и написать самому, если бы понимал как написал бы. Если вы владеете какой либо информацией как именно писать, поделитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: @AlexNem Пусть будет именно для той строки которую я указал в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос оформлен доступно, побольше бы таких...

1) 2 массива можно объединить в один, где ключи - русские символы, значение - английские.

2) Вместо `for` можно использовать `foreach` по тому самому массиву.

3) Цикл `for` с `preg_replace` не нужен, ибо последний параметр соответствует количеству замен и он равен `$rand`.

4) В целях оптимизации, можно не запускать цикл с заменой, если замен 0.

---

Из выше перечисленного теперь код будет выглядеть так:

```
$string = "Наша Таня громко плачет, уронила в речку мячик.";

$symbol_array = array(
    "а" => 'a',
    "с" => 'c',
    "е" => 'e',
    "о" => '0'
);

foreach ($symbol_array as $symbol_array_key => $symbol_array_value) {
    $rand = rand(0, substr_count($string, $symbol_array_key));
    if ($rand > 0) {
        $string = preg_replace("/" . $symbol_array_key . "/", $symbol_array_value, $string, $rand);
    }
}

echo $string;
```

Comment: Да, сразу видно опыт. Спасибо за ответ. Использую его.

Answer (score 0):

Наверняка найдется более элегантный и правильный код, но вот как мне удалось решить данный вопрос самостоятельно.

```
#Исходный текст.
$string = "Наша Таня громко плачет, уронила в речку мячик.";

#Массив с русскими буквами.
$symbol_ru = array(
    "а",
    "с",
    "е",
    "о"
);

#Массив с английскими буквами.
$symbol_en = array(
    "a",
    "c",
    "e",
    "o"
);

#Создаём цикл и выводим буквы из массива.
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($symbol_ru); $i++) {

    #Считаем количество найденных букв в исходном тексте.
    $substr_count = substr_count($string, $symbol_ru[$i]);

    #Создаём случаное число в приделе найденных букв.
    $rand = rand(0, $substr_count);

    #Создаём цикл, с количество повторений полученных в $rand.
    for ($j = 0; $j <= $rand; $j++) {

        #Ищем первое вхождение и заменяем на английскую букву.
        $string = preg_replace("/" . $symbol_ru[$i] . "/", $symbol_en[$i], $string, 1);

    }

}

#Выводим результат.
echo $string;
```

Я так думаю что с массивами можно по другому поступить, но не уверен. Если вы знаете как улучшить данный код, буду рад если вы укажете как. Всем мир.